# SHChangeNotify not refreshing icon for Virtual Keyboard after registry toggle

Tags: winapi, registry, explorer, virtual-keyboard, taskbar

I've got a registry key that gets set to show the Virtual Keyboard for Windows 10 1703 Creators Update.

You can run it yourself if you throw this in a `.reg` file after manually disabling it to perform the same test I'm trying out:

#### show_vkb.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7]
"TipbandDesiredVisibility"=dword:00000001
```

I'm basically trying to toggle this on for the user:

[image: show_vkb]

So that involves two end-goals:

1. Updating the registry key and refreshing whatever references it
2. Refreshing the taskbar so the Virtual Keyboard icon appears, as shown below:

[image: vkb_icon]

I was led to understand that using SHChangeNotify should refresh the explorer shell. I've verified that it's refreshing *part* of the taskbar, specifically the App icons, but it's not refreshing the virtual peripherals shown on the taskbar.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>

int main()
{
    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing/doing wrong here. I've tried a couple different parameter combos with the different MACRO values listed for [SHChangeNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118(v=vs.85).aspx), but no progress.

Comment: "SHChangeNotify should refresh the explorer shell" - it is not correct. SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED) will refresh icon, file types descriptions and other things related to file type associations. When I see your screenshot I don`t understand what should be changed. Could you explain in details?

Comment: Thanks, @DenisAnisimov; I've updated the question. Does that provide everything you were curious about?

Comment: When I change this setting in menu all app receives WM_SETTINGCHANGE message with "TraySettings" param. But all my experiments with SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 'TraySettings'), BroadcastSystemMessage(BSF_FORCEIFHUNG, nil, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 'TraySettings'), SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 'TraySettings') failed.

Comment: What makes you think `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED` is the correct `wEventId` to use in the first place? You are not modifying a "file type association". Try using [`SHChangeNotifyRegister()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120.aspx) to listen for `SHChangeNotify()` events, and then see what events (if any) are sent out when the menu updates the settings normally. That might help you understand why your `SHChangeNotify()` call is not working.

Comment: When the system broadcasts `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` with `lParam='TraySettings'`, what is the value of `wParam`? You are setting the `wParam` to 0 in your manual broadcast.  Also, are you running elevated when sending the broadcast?  If not, UIPI may be blocking your broadcasts

Comment: (I am not topic starter) wParam = 0. Tried with elevated mode - no effect.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I had to choose one set of parameters to use for my code sample :) So I chose the most common one that is advised, probably because of this reason: "Applications that register new handlers of any type must call `SHChangeNotify` with the `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED` flag to instruct the Shell to invalidate the icon and thumbnail cache. " But yeah, I've tried some of the others too without luck. I've also tried `SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);` and `SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, 
 &dwResult);`

Comment: Also, I have tried all these as both Elevated/Admin as well as the current user.

Comment: The registry is not a programming interface. Are you sure you are going about this the right way?

Comment: @IInspectable I would argue that no, I'm not going about this the right way xD Just a way that apparently should have worked. I'd be more than happy to read your alternative suggestions though!